# How can I paint a sector only with border-radius?

Tags: html, css

As we know, in CSS, we can use:

```
width : 100px; height : 100px; border-radius : 100% 0 0 0;
```

To paint a sector with 90deg; and I want to use this way to paint a sector with any deg. But the front sector doesn't cover perfectly. It leaks a slice of red sector and I don't know how to handle it.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fbb;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0;
}

.box::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fbb;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: While I've edited your question to *try* and make it more readable I have to point out that your first block of CSS is formatted incorrectly; the `=` characters should - for all those instances - be replaced with `:`

Comment: [You don't need those vendor prefixes](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_transform-origin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cheat a bit and shift the whole overlay with an additional transform.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fbb;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0;
}

.box::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fbb;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-1px, 0px); /* <---- here */
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

It also seems to work by shifting the transform origin slightly.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fbb;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0;
}

.box::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fbb;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0;
  transform-origin: 101% 100%; /* <---- here */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

You could also use a sharp box shadow.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fbb;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0;
}

.box::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fbb;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .5px #fbb; /* <---- here */
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

None of these are mathematically perfect, but they may suit your practical needs.